# Corova - Angular - Ionic : Implement a loader before bootstrapping angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loader, ionic-framework

I'm using this code to bootstrap mi Angular app when I get the deviceReady event (or force it manuelly when testing in the browser):

```
var PhoneGapInit = function () {
  this.boot = function () {
    console.log("starting angular");
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['cmmApp']);
  };

  if (window.cordova !== undefined) {
    console.log("Found Cordova");
    var _this = this;
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
      _this.boot();
    });
  } else {
    console.log('PhoneGap not found, booting Angular manually');
    this.boot();
  }
};

//this start angular
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
  new PhoneGapInit();
});
```

But I would like to create a loader and hide the "dirty & unstyled" html code before the app load. Any Idea on how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with ng-cloak to hide elements before angular bootstrap app

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: Thanks this is a good solution. Is there any way to get the percent of loading?